# Exception is undefined when app is on remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, exception

When I make an $http call to API, and it throws an exception from my MVC controller, I log the exception message that is returned to my Angular code with

```
.then(function success(response){ // success },
      function error(response){ console.log(JSON.stringify(response);};})
```

This works and the custom exception message is displayed. However when I deploy the app on a remote server on IIS, when an exception is thrown, the `response` parameter is always:

```
{"data":{"Message":"An error has occurred."},"status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":...,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

...basically, it doesn't contain the custom Exception message, it will always simply have "An error has occurred."

Could this be a routing error, a.k.a the exception doesn't actually reach my Angular side? My logic behind this is because the remote URL looks like:

`website.com/extension` , and on my local it is `website.com`

Comment: Try to access API directly in your browser and see it works. If it doesn't, then check your IIS logs.

Comment: Errors with stack trace are only shown locally unless you change it on your web.config: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684665.aspx

Comment: can't check logs atm, will do when able. like you said, I tried `website.com/extension/api/controller/action` and it returned an XML with a Message in an Error tag. When I do it from `website.com/api/controller/action`, I get Message, ExceptionMessage, ExceptionType and StackTrace in the Error tag... looks like it's cutting those extra properties off for some reason.

Comment: @Gusman Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, for security reasons, the full error message is not sent to the client when accessed from a remote machine as it could reveal sensitive data. You can modify the `web.config` to return the details to remote machines by setting the `customErrors` mode to `Off`. However, you should not do so without considering the security implications first.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

A better practice is to give a generic error message to the client "Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred!" and record the actual error message on the server in your logs.